# Question does not gain answers in Math Stack Exchange. Would a migration to StackOverflow be a solution?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, bounty, migration

I recently asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608669/singular-procedure-vanishing-polynomial-function-a-singular-introduction-to-co) question in Math Stack Exchange but does not gain any answers even though I bountied it.

It seems either there aren‘t many people familiar with the Singular-CAS in Math Stack Exchange or maybe I should phrase my question in a different way. Does this question maybe belong to StackOverflow?

This thread is **not** about gaining more clicks on my question but rather to figure out how I could phrase my question better or if I did ask it in the wrong forum.

Comment: As a contributor on both Math.SE and StackOverflow, I believe you made the right choice to post here.  It may be that "there aren't many people familiar with the Singular-CAS" here, but tiny though that percentage may be, it would still be better to be on Math.SE because of the importance of the underlying Commutative Algebra concepts.

Comment: Perhaps the tag ([meta-tag:specific-question]) would be suitable here? (The question is whether you ask mainly about this particular question, or whether the linked question is just an example and you're interested in a more general question what to do in similar situations. See [the tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-question/info) for more details about this tag.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bounty was only placed somewhat recently. There might still be hope.

As you speculate I assume there are not that many users familiar with Singular on the site. I doubt that Stack Overflow would be better. They do not have a tag for it, as far as I can tell, and this likely means it will fall through the cracks (especially if it is a migration).

You might consider asking it on the [Computational Science Stack Exchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). It is not an ideal fit there either, as the site is more about numerical problems and alike. But as far as I know such questions are in principle on-topic there.

Other than that, maybe try dedicated support resources for Singular, such as the forum on https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will wait until the bounty is expired and try the Computational Science Stack Exchange after that. I already considered to use the Singular-forum but it does not seem that there is a active community answering questions.

Comment: I never used that forum (not even Singular for that matter); it does not seem very populated that's true, but there do seem to be timely reactions to posts. And, the people replying there should be experts. I mean it's only a slight stretch to say that forum is run by the very authors of the book you ask about.

Comment: You might also try at https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/ It's a Q&A for Sage, but this includes Singular. I am not sure if they consider it on-topic there, but maybe.